# For which $z$ is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})z^n$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out for which complex $z$ the series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})z^n$$
is convergent. I tried finding $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})$ by the root test and quotient test, using Taylor expansion, but got nowhere. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $1-\cos(1/n)\sim1/2n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {1-\cos \theta} {\theta^{2}} \to \frac 1  2$ as $ \theta \to 0$ (by either the series expansion or L'hopital's Rule). Hence the given series convrges iff $\sum (1/n^{2})z^n$ converges. By ratio test this is so iff $|z|\leq 1$.

[For $|z|=1$ you can use Comparison Test].

Comment: "Hence the given series convrges iff $\sum(1/n^2)z^n$ converges." What theorem do you use to draw that conclusion?

Comment: @SimonSMN If $\frac {b_n} {a_n}$ converges to a  non-zero limit then  $\sum b_n$ converges absolutely iff $\sum a_n$ does. This can be proved easily  using Comparison Test.